# Repeating group or not

Tags: database-design, repeat, database-normalization

Is SName in the following table considered a repeating group?

Each of the subject listed in the SName field is in a separate cell. As far as I know a repeating group is when a cell contains more than one value. Therefore I am not sure since the subjects are in separate cells.

Comment: A dead link was edited out of this. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Insert images/links using edit functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, SName is just one field of the repeating group. The repeating group are all the S* fields (SCode, SName, SMark, SMax, SPerc). The group would be named Student then.